# Why do we need upcasting cell obtained by dequeueReusableCell func?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am very confused about fact that  in

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MessageCell
    if let message = messages?[indexPath.item] {
        cell.message = message
    }
    cell.timeLibel
    return cell
}
```

i supposed to upcast cell to a class implied by reuseIdentifier. So it turns out (in my case) the result of deqeueReusableCell function is not a MessageCell class even if i had registered exactly it

```
 collectionView?.register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

moreover when i try to see is it real not the MessageCell instance by

```
cell.isKind(of: MessageCell.self)
```

it returns true. But at the same time when I am trying to access instance properties of MessageCell class it throws an error "Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'message"

But reference said:

> After dequeueing the appropriate view in your delegate method,
>   configure its content and return it to the collection view for use.

and from reference of UICollectionViewDataSource:

> Your implementation of this method is responsible for creating,
>   configuring, and returning the appropriate cell for the given item.
>   You do this by calling the
>   dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:) method of the collection
>   view and passing the reuse identifier that corresponds to the cell
>   type you want.

Why do we need to upcast 
**let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)**       ?

Here is MessageCell etc

```
 class MessageCell: BaseCell {
var message: Message? {
    didSet {
        nameLabel.text = message?.friend?.name
        if let profileImageName = message?.friend?.profileImageName {
            profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: profileImageName)
            messageLabel.text = message?.text
        }
    }
}
let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 34
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return imageView
}()

let dividerLineView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.5)
    return view
}()
    let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Mark Zuckerberg"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
//    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
    return label
}()

let messageLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Your friends message and something else..."
    label.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
//    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    return label
}()


let timelabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "12:05 pm"
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
    label.textAlignment = .right
//    label.textColor = UIColor.white
//    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    return label

}()

let hasReadImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
   imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    return imageView
}()
override func setupViews() {

    addSubview(profileImageView)
     addSubview(dividerLineView)
    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zuckprofile")
    hasReadImageView.image = UIImage(named: "zuckprofile")
    setupContainerView()

    addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|-12-[v0(68)]|", views: profileImageView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:[v0(68)]", views: profileImageView)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: profileImageView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|-82-[v0]|", views: dividerLineView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:[v0(1)]|", views: dividerLineView)



}
func setupContainerView() {
    let containerView = UIView()
     addSubview(containerView)

    addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-90-[v0]|", views: containerView)
    addConstraintsWithFormat(  "V:[v0(50)]", views: containerView)
    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    containerView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(messageLabel)
    containerView.addSubview(timelabel)
    containerView.addSubview(hasReadImageView)
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|[v0][v1(80)]-12-|", views: nameLabel, timelabel )
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:|[v0(26)][v1(24)]|", views: nameLabel,messageLabel )
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "H:|[v0]-8-[v1(20)]-12-|", views: messageLabel, hasReadImageView )
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0(20)]|", views: hasReadImageView)
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat( "V:|[v0(24)]", views: timelabel)
   addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: nameLabel, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: timelabel, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: -1.4 ))


}

}



 extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String , views: UIView...) {
    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
    for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
}
}



 class BaseCell : UICollectionViewCell {
let a = 5
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
    layer.masksToBounds = true
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

}
 }
```

Comment: If i remember rightly, isKindOf will check that the object can be casted to that type successfully. It doesn't actually cast it that way though. You need to do this yourself as only you will know what type you have registered for that reuseIdentifier

Comment: please take another look for my question

Comment: isKind(of:)
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the receiver is an instance of given class or an instance of any class that inherits from that class.

Comment: what does MessageCell look like?

Comment: @Scriptable I added it to my question please check it

Comment: You need to downcast because the declaration of `dequeueReusableCell` says that it returns a `UICollectionViewCell`; if you know that it is actually returning a subclass then you need to downcast it in order to access the properties of the subclass.  You are registering the class using a conditional unwrap; are you sure that `collectionView` has a value at that point?

Comment: yes it has)  
"You need to downcast because the declaration of dequeueReusableCell says that it returns a UICollectionViewCell" yes it is, but i wondered why if we dont modify cell in collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) method, but just preconfigure it from MessageCell class, it shows real preconfigured MessageCell class not  UICollectionViewCell base class exactly MessageCell , but when i try to modify it suddenly it forget about it.

Comment: (moreover we are registered (register(MessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)) from the begining not UICollectionViewCell base class.

Comment: This is a difference between what happens at build time and at run time.  The definition of the dequeue function says it returns a UICollectionView cell which means it can also be a subclass of it which your MessageCell is.  So at build time the compiler does not know what is going the be returned (no compiling has taken place to determine this) so you must downcast to the correct type.  However at run time the system knows exactly what it is and so can determine the correct type.

Comment: The definition of the dequeue function says  - Returns a reusable cell object located by its identifier. Then why do func need reuseIdentifier parameter?

Answer (score 1):

dequeueReusable is use for memory efficiency purpose. The way it works in lower level my friend has detail explanation on that https://medium.com/ios-seminar/why-we-use-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-ce7fd97cde8e

I hope it answered your question.